# how to construct self-energie diagrams

Tags: feynman-diagrams, many-body, self-energy

I am working on self-energie and feynmann diagrams. they are not very easy to get but i think i am starting to understand how it works but of course i am not realy sure.and before going any further i would like to know if the flowing statements are correct.

1. The dyson equation states that when doing perturbation theory
   instead of calculating all diagrams we can restrict our self to
   irreducible ones.

now the next question is how to construct the diagrams !

one should first inspect the interaction there is no rule that holds for every interaction. by inspecting the interaction we can see that the diagrams has to respect some conservation law and some other conditions that depend on the interaction considered.

if i am correct then what i found for the Hubbard model is the following:

1. It's better to treat spin up and down particles like if they were
   different and associate to each one it's own propagator.
2. There is momentum conservation but the two particles can't
   exchange momentum.
3. (this one i am not very sure of) While constructing diagrams for
   the irreducible self-energie of the spin-up particle if we have n
   spin-up propagator then we should have n+1 spin-down propagator.